# asp.net bind a list to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List<MasterBook> listOfBooks = new List<MasterBook>();
```

after i put the masterbook objects which by the way have 3 fields( name,id and active ) into the list

```
 GridView1.DataSource = listOfBooks;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

in the web form

```
   <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="BookNameText" runat="server" 
                            Text="<%#Container.DataItem%>">

                    </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

the problem is that i want to display the bookmaster's name in the gridview column
this code print bookmaster in the column how can i make it type the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to MasterBook:

```
Text="<%# ((MasterBook) Container.DataItem).Name %>">
```

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
  <%#Container.DataItem%>
```

To:

```
  <%#Eval("name")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick, dirty hack workaround is to overload the `ToString()` method of your `MasterBook`class in order to return that name. Commit seppuku afterwards if you do it.

The elegant and graceful way is to make [an object datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That way you can bind the grid view's columns to the objects' properties. In the case of a DataList or other templated data controls, you can bind your objects' properties to the data control's child controls in their templates.

The middle path is in hutchonoid's answer: evaluate a property of the object, not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sintax:

```
<asp:Label ID="BookNameText" runat="server" 
                        Text="<%# ((MasterBook)Container.DataItem).Name %>">
```